# OpenStreamForWriteAsync Doesn't finish

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am trying to save a serialised object to a file. When I call the `OpenStreamForWriteAsync` method the UI locks up and the process never seems to end. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
            public async Task<string> Save(string fileName)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Settings));

        serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);

        ms.Position = 0;

        try
        {
            using (var fms = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(fms, this);
                return "Saved successfully";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Could not save.";
        }

    }
```

This is my first question on StackOverflow, but have been a long time learner. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You've already serialized the object to the memory stream, don't you want to just write the memory stream to the async file rather than calling the serializer a second time?

Comment: Yeah, I just want to write the memory stream to a file.

Comment: I don't have the Metro development environment installed so I can't test an exact replica of what you're doing, but replacing the line `serializer.WriteObject(fms, this);` with `await ms.CopyToAsync(fms);` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I was not awaiting when calling this method. Needed to call the method using:

```
string result =  await Settings.Save("settings.xml");
```

Will rename the method to `SaveAsync` as a reminder.